# Prove that a sequence sup $a_n\ne1$

Tags: sequences-and-series, supremum-and-infimum

I have to prove the following:

> Let $(a_n)$ be a sequence such that $(a_n)<1$. Prove or disprove:
>
> If $(\frac{1} {1-a_n} )$ is bounded from above, then $\sup(a_n) \ne 1$.

I was thinking that I can prove the statement with the fact that if the sequence is bounded from above then $(\frac{1} {1-a_n} )<M$, by definition.

Now assume in contradiction that  $\sup(a_n) =1$. Since $(a_n)<1$, $(\frac{1} {1-a_n} )>0$.

From above we come the a conclusion that $(a_n)<0$ which means the the supremum  isn't 1.

Is my solution right? I know formality needs some work.

Comment: What about $a_n = 0$?

Comment: How do you conclude that $a_n < 0$? You get $a_n < 1-\frac{1}{M}$, without the need to assume $\sup a_n = 1$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: If 
$$
\frac{1}{1-a_n}<M,
$$
then since $1-a_n>0$, we have 
$$
\frac{1}{M}<1-a_n,
$$
which gives 
$$
a_n<1-\frac{1}{M}
$$